# Docker Compose ECS Having Issues Creating Load Balancer

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb

I'm trying to deploy multiple services to Amazon ECS by using Docker Compose (I know it's retiring soon, it's part of my job training), and it's failing with the error

```
A load balancer cannot be attached to multiple subnets in the same Availability Zone (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancing; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidConfigurationRequest; Request ID: 66415eb3-da76-447a-9c46-94838c05d0a9; Proxy: null)
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this as I should just be using the automatic load balancer.

My colleagues are also working to do the same steps, and get past creating the load balancer, and none of us can figure out why, given we have the same `docker-compose.yml` file. We also checked the `docker compose convert`s, and mine is significantly more verbose for some reason.

Here's the yml file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  account-server:
    container_name: account-server
    image: 651872020896.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/account-server:latest
    ports: 
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - binary-banking-network
    env_file:
      - .env
  auth-server:
    container_name: auth-server
    image: 651872020896.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/auth-server:latest
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    networks:
      - binary-banking-network
    env_file:
      - .env
  branch-server:
    container_name: branch-server
    image: 651872020896.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/branch-server:latest
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    networks:
      - binary-banking-network
    env_file:
      - .env
  card-server:
    container_name: card-server
    image: 651872020896.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/card-server:latest
    ports: 
      - 8083:8083
    networks:
      - binary-banking-network
    env_file:
      - .env
  user-server:
    container_name: user-server
    image: 651872020896.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/user-server:latest
    ports:
      - 8085:8085
    networks:
      - binary-banking-network
    env_file:
      - .env
networks:
  binary-banking-network:
    driver: bridge
```